# Native Dynamic Linq (C#)

Tags: c#, dynamic

Is it possible to utilise the `dynamic` keyword in c# 5.0 (.Net 4.5) to create a dynamic LINQ query?

I know this is possible using third party libraries, but this is not viable right now.

The easiest way to illustrate my point is through an example:

```
    class test
    {
        public int i { get; set; }
    }

    void Foo()
    {
        var collection = new[] { new test() { i = 1 }, new test() { i = 2 } };
        Bar(collection);
    }

    void Bar<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        //this works
        foreach (dynamic item in collection)
            if (item.i == 2)
            {
                //do something
            }

        //this does not - although this is what id like to use
        foreach (dynamic item in collection.Where(a => a.i == 2))
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

Edit per request: Produces a compiler error -

> 'T' does not contain a definition for 'i' and no extension method 'i' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Please add specific runtime/compiler errors.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the T in Bar declaration to use dynamic :

```
void Bar(IEnumerable<dynamic> collection)
{
    //this works
    foreach (dynamic item in collection)
        if (item.i == 2)
        {
            //do something
        }

    //this does compile
    foreach (dynamic item in collection.Where(a => a.i == 2))
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this alot. I would also take a wild guess and say there is no performance penalty when comparied with the original `Bar()`

Comment: I don't know about performance, but I really hate the loss of compile time checking. Be sure to cover this with thorough unit testing.

Comment: Agreed.  Using `dynamic` always makes me feel slightly dirty.